# Error:(12, 32) error: attribute value must be constant when declaring String for toast for ACRA toast

Tags: android, toast, acra

I'm trying to introduce the ACRA lib in my library project. When I set up the String for the toast, I get a "Attribute value must be a constant" error. Please see attached screen-shots
[image]

and the R.string.crash_toast_text:
[image]

Please note that these lines of code are from here

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#toast-notification

Comment: Is this code in an application or a library?

Comment: is in a library, I forgot to mention, apologies

Comment: I suspect that's your problem there. ACRA is really meant to be configured in an application module, not a library module, and so the docs reflect that bias. `R` values for a library are generated as non-constant values (which is why you can't use them in a `case` statement). I suspect that you'll need to replace the annotation with setting up the `ACRAConfiguration` in Java code more directly.

Comment: It appears that `R.string.crash_toast_text` is not declared as `final`. I suspect this is because you are developing a library project rather than a application project. Are you using Android Studio, gradle, and the "new" directory structure (as opposed to the old Eclipse structure)?

Comment: @ CommonsWare, you're suggestion worked. If you post it as an answer, I all accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on CommonsWare 18 answer, I made it work. Here is a sample code if anyone gets stuck in the same situation:

```
 final ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig(this);

    try {
        config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST);
    } catch (ACRAConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    config.setResToastText(R.string.crash_toast_text);
    ACRA.init(this, config);
```